# Euler-Bernoulli beam: negative eigenvalues

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

Separation of variables for the [dynamic beam equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Dynamic_beam_equation) yields the equation
$$ u'''' = \lambda u .$$

If $\lambda > 0$ is assumed, then the general solution is given by

$$    u = A_1\cosh(\beta x) + A_2\sinh(\beta x) + A_3\cos(\beta x) + A_4\sin(\beta x) \quad \text{with} \quad \beta := +\lambda^{1/4} $$

How do we show that $\lambda < 0$ only permits the trivial solutions? None of the resources  ([ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory), [ex](https://personal.egr.uri.edu/sadd/mce565/Ch5.pdf)) I find consider this alternative.

For example, assume boundary conditions: $u(0) = u'(0) = u(1) = u'(1) = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps such a situation would simply be non-physical? I have $\lambda = \frac{\mu \omega^2}{EI},$ and I don't see how $\mu, E,$ or $I$ are ever going to be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda=-4\nu^4<0$, so $\lambda^{1/4}=(\pm1\pm i)\nu$ and hence
$$
u=\sum_{\mu=\pm 1\pm i}A_\mu\exp(\mu\nu x)
$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
0=u(0)&=\sum_{\mu=\pm 1\pm i}A_\mu\\
0=u'(0)&=\sum_{\mu=\pm 1\pm i}A_\mu\mu\nu\\
0=u(1)&=\sum_{\mu=\pm 1\pm i}A_\mu\exp(\mu\nu)\\
0=u'(1)&=\sum_{\mu=\pm 1\pm i}A_\mu\mu\nu\exp(\mu\nu)
\end{align*}
Now the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1+i&\exp(( 1+i)\nu)&( 1+i)\exp(( 1+i)\nu)\\
1& 1-i&\exp(( 1-i)\nu)&( 1-i)\exp(( 1-i)\nu)\\
1&-1+i&\exp((-1+i)\nu)&(-1+i)\exp((-1+i)\nu)\\
1&-1-i&\exp((-1-i)\nu)&(-1-i)\exp((-1-i)\nu)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is invertible (exercise), so $A_\mu=0$ for all $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer. I would argue that the columns are $(const., \;t,\; \exp(t),\; t \exp(t))$, and therefore likely to be invertible (for any $\nu$). Is this how you would do it?

Comment: @Patrick compute determinant.

Comment: Sure, but in order to do that I have to assume a value for $\nu$, which I don't want to.

Comment: You don't need to assume a value.  It can stay inside exp(...).  The result is $8(2-\cos(2\nu)-\cosh(2\nu))$ which is negative for every $\nu>0$.

Comment: You're right, I don't need it! I thought you meant me to compute it numerically, since I don't recall ever computing a 4-by-4 determinant by hand. If you don't mind me asking, how did you obtain the analytical formula so fast? Mathematica? Because I'm taking very long by hand...

Comment: Just elementary row/column operations, e.g., $r_1,r_2\mapsto r_1+r_2, r_1-r_2$ doubles the determinant.  I took out the nonzero $\nu$ from the second and fourth columns.